# PyMongo connection refused

Tags: python, mongodb, connection, debian, pymongo

I've installed **pymongo** via ***pip*** as I have done many times before.
From a python shell (on the same server), I can successfully run:

```
>>> import pymongo
```

without error. However, when attempting to establish a client connection as follows:

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient()
```

I receive a:

```
pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

PyMongo is happily sitting in my *dist-packages* and so seems to be installed properly. However, it doesn't seem to be running / listening. Running the commands:

```
user@host:~$ mongod
-bash: mongod: command not found
user@host:~$ mongodb
-bash: mongodb: command not found
```

results in ***command not found*** errors and, additionally, it doesn't seem to be a recognized service: That said; it must be installed as I used:

```
pip install pymongo
```

Equally, the two suggested solutions I have found aren't relevant as the referenced files don't seem to exist. *(removing a mongodb lock)* and *(editing the BIND_IP directive of a mongos.conf file)*. Neither the lock nor the file exist.

Is this something particular to pymongo? What is the likely cause of this connection refusal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoul have MongoDB install and mongod running on your system.
`pip install pymongo` doesn't [**install**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/) MongoDB

Comment: PyMongo doesn't install Mongo as a dependency?

Comment: @JordanDolan NO. see my answer

Comment: It won't let me accept until another 9 mins have passed but I will do.